# SvelteKit Form Action not returning success / remains null

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following setup in my +page.server.js:

```
export const actions = {
    createScore: async ({ request }) => {
        const values = await request.formData();

        try {
            const instagram = values.get('username');
            const score = Number(values.get('score'));

            await prisma.score.create({
                data: {
                    score,
                    instagram
                }
            });

            return { success: true };
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return fail(500, { message: 'Could not create the score.' });
        }
    }
};
```

This runs fine, I see the entry in the database. However, no matter how hard I try, I cannot access 'form' to check for the return of sucess in my front end.

I do the following in page.svelte

```
<script>
    export let form;
    console.log(form);
</script>
```

The console log consistently returns null when the form is run.

Further, the following never renders (telling me I am not missing a state change):

```
{#if form?.success}
<p>It Worked</p>
{/if}
```

Finally, form as follows:

```
<form action="?/createScore" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="score" name="score" />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Show the `form` that triggers the action.

Comment: Also, if anything, you would want to log reactively: `$: console.log(form);`

Comment: Thanks @H.B., I have added the form (its very simple - stripped down for trying to get to teh route cause). Tried this to see if anything changed but didnt get a subsequent console.log.

Comment: One addition, I also removed all the database stuff entirely and just returned success but this didnt seem to work either

Comment: I do not see any issues here. The page file is named `+page.svelte`, correct? Also, would recommend using the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance) to not fully reload the page on submit.

Comment: It is but strangely, enhance seems to have done it and I am now getting something back! Thanks

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could create a minimal example of the issue (when not using `enhance`) and report that in [the respective repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues). Forms should still work as intended when no JS is running on the client.

Comment: Forms are really a far fetched concept from handling things. Have bumped into cross-side requests errors, routes `n-svelte/blob/main/docs/faq.md#where-should-i-put-my-global-styles.
The "/[lang]" and "/[lang]/(app)" routes conflict with each other` and along other problemts.

Comment: Ran into same issue today, adding use:enhance solved it. Not sure why it was necessary though

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot access 'form' to check for the return of success in my front end.

Maybe different in your case, but I came across the same issue once when I first started learning SvelteKit.

In my case, I had turned off server-side rendering in a `+layout.js` file so that I could access the `window` object on the frontend:

`export const ssr = false;` (I got that [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/3365).)

Commenting out that line (along with re-working the way that I handled localstorage access) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could fix it by moving the `Form` from a component to `+page.svelte`.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had a variable with the same name as the actionData. When I changed it it worked.